# Cypress - Different results using cypress:open and cypress:run

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this simple page (a notfound page) in vue2 (but it's simple plain HTML):

`NotFound.vue`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <base-card>
      <h2 id="notFoundTitle">This isn't the page you are looking for.</h2>

      <p>
        404 - This page could not be found - check out all our
        <router-link to="/coaches">coaches</router-link>
      </p>
    </base-card>
  </section>
</template>
```

now i created this simple test in Cypress:

`notLogged.cy.js`

```
let siteUrl = 'https://my.site'

describe('Tests for pages without login', () => {
  describe('Tests for the home page', () => {
   
    it('Tests the not found page', async () => {
      let url = siteUrl + '/stuff'

      cy.visit(url)
      let pageTitle = cy.get('#notFoundTitle')
      let pagePar = cy.get('p')

      expect(pageTitle).to.exist
      expect(pagePar).to.exist

      pageTitle.should('have.text', "This isn't the page you are looking for.")
      pagePar.should('contain', '404')
    })
  })
})
```

my `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "test_cy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run notLogged.cy.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.6.3"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run cypress:run` everything works fine and says that the 2 tests have passed.

BUT when I run `npm run cypress:open` and i use chrome for e2e testing, it throws an absurd error, shown in image:

[image]

but i am not searching for `p` which `'have.text'`.
I am searching for `p`which `contains` the string `404`.

the error (reported from image) is:

```
assert expected '<p>' to have text 'This isn't the page you are looking for.', but the text was **'&nbsp;404 - This page could not be found - check out all our coaches'**
(uncaught exception)AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<p>' to have text 'This isn't the page you are looking for.', but the text was ' 404 - This page could not be found - check out all our coaches'
```

Does someone have an idea why or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? You clearly have `p` and `have.text` in your file, and the error says it can't find that text in `p`. The text you are looking for is in `h2`.

Comment: well, the `expect` #1 says that element with id `notFoundTitle` should have text `This isn't...`; `expect` #2 says that element `p` should contain `404`. I didn't do any test saying that `p` should have text `This isn't...`. It mixed the two tests.

Answer (score 4):

In the Cypress documentation [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values) it tells you

> ***You cannot assign or work with the return values*** of any Cypress command.
> Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

Internally, Cypress tracks the `subject` of the chain, and uses it to evaluate  assertions.

The last query before the assertions is `cy.get('p')` so the subject is `<p>` not the `<h2>` in variable `pageTitle`.

---

The standard way to code this test is with complete command chains

```js
cy.visit('https://vue-course-2023.web.app/stuff')

cy.get('#notFoundTitle').should('exist')
  .and('have.text', "This isn't the page you are looking for.")
  
cy.get('p').should('exist')
  .and('contain', '404')
```

[image]

or with aliases, if you want to break the chain, for some reason

```js
cy.visit('https://vue-course-2023.web.app/stuff')

cy.get('#notFoundTitle').as('pageTitle')
cy.get('p').as('pageParagraph')

// some intermediate code

cy.get('@pageTitle')
  .should('exist')
  .and('have.text', "This isn't the page you are looking for.")
  
cy.get('@pageParagraph')
  .should('exist')
  .and('contain', '404')
```

[image]

---

**BTW** The test also failed in run mode when I ran it.

Comment: Thanks man, I searched through the documentation and I realized that my code was basically wrong. I still didn't have an answer for it's behaviour, so thank you for the explanation :) Still I don't know why it didn't fail in run mode for me, but it fails for you, but I think this will be a question without an answer :)